# "Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation" in c++ std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, valgrind

Valgrind tells me that there is an error in my code, but I am not able to find it...
here is a code snippet:

```
22 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
...
//argv[1] contains the name of a file
int length=atoi(argv[2]);
map<string, double> Map;
char* Key;
Key = new char [length+1];
...
```

I also used `Key[length]='\0'` but this does't seem to affect the rest of the code.

now I fill in the map with entries taken from a file (which contains a list of keys and values rows. The dimension of Key is always lower of length.

```
while( file_stream >> Key >> Value){
Map[Key]=Value;
....
}
```

at this point, I call:

```
cout << Key  << " has value ";
159   cout << Map[Key] << endl;
```

The program is compiled and executed nicely, but Valgrind give lots of errors of this type:

```
==6921== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6921==    at 0x56274A0: __printf_fp (printf_fp.c:404)
==6921==    by 0x562396A: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1622)
==6921==    by 0x5648C81: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:120)
==6921==    by 0x4EB64AE: ??? (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==6921==    by 0x4EB9002: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_float<double>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, char, double) const (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==6921==    by 0x4EB9328: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, double) const (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==6921==    by 0x4ECCC9E: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<double>(double) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==6921==    by 0x40366E: main (MyProgram.cpp:159)
==6921==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==6921==    at 0x401C61: main (MyProgram.cpp:22)
```

Do you have any idea any clue? I would prefer to not post all the long code (please don't blame for this)

Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you have a `map<string,double>`  but then use a dynamically allocated `char* Key` instead of a `string Key`?

Comment: "Do you have any idea why I did this error" - *Why* you did this error? Not a clue. Hard to climb into that thought-process. **Post the *real*, *compilable* code**.

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right, I edited the question.

Comment: @us2012 thank you for your hint, I am going to correct the code and see what happens.

Comment: Please post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) here and/or ideone.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace implies that you are formatting a `double`. There is no way an uninitialized `double` can be obtained from `Map[Key]` unless you explicitly stuck an uninitialized `double` into it (even the `Key` doesn't exist in `Map`, it would be initialized using `double()`). This could point to a piece of interesting code within the implementation of `__printf_fp()`: I'd verify with a simple test program whether this report, indeed, can be reproduced using, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << 3.14;
}
```

... and, if so, I'd just ignore the report from `valgrind`. During a really calm afternoon it may be reaosnable to dig through the implementation of `__printf_fp()` to find where it does something questionable and determine whether it actually matters (I'd not gamble on that ever happening to me, though: I'd rather implement floating point formatting myself which woudl, however, probably take a lot more than one afternoon as it is distinctly non-trivial).

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not able to read the output of Valgrind, so I concentrated my attention to  the map itself, instead of value... but there were a uninitialized value there...